# Fuzzing tool: Mutate integer within predefined range?

Tags: testing, fuzzing, fuzzer

I am newbie to fuzzing tools, and basically, I would like to use fuzzing tool to test a specific function.

Essentially, this function has three input parameter, and each parameter is a number, with range 0 to `0xffff`.

I would like to use a fuzzing tool to generate random input combinations, and test the target function. However, I tried `zzuf`, but find that it does not have a specific setting on mutating integer value..

So I am looking for a fuzzer, that supports to only mutate integer value, within a predefined range? Could anyone give me some help on this issue? Am I clear enough? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with many tools, among them [Kitty](https://github.com/cisco-sas/kitty) (developed by my team).

Assuming you want to generate the number with decimal representation, the following template will generate them for you (values will be comma-separated):

```
from kitty.model import *
t = Template(name='function inputs', fields=[
    S32(name='p1', value=1, min_value=-500, max_value=1000, encoder=ENC_INT_DEC),
    Static(','),
    ForEach(name='p2', mutated_field='p1',
            fields=S32(value=2, min_value=-3200, max_value=5098, encoder=ENC_INT_DEC)),
    Static(','),
    ForEach(name='p3', mutated_field='p2',
            fields=S32(value=3, min_value=0, max_value=999, encoder=ENC_INT_DEC))
])

while t.mutate():
    print t.render().tobytes()
```

Some example results:

```
-1,2,3
129,1026,3
129,130,3
129,18,3
129,-3200,3
129,5098,3
129,-3199,3
129,5097,3
129,-3198,3
129,5096,3
129,3,3
129,1,3
129,4,3
129,0,3
17,1026,3
17,130,3
17,18,3
17,-3200,3
17,5098,3
17,-3199,3
```